# What seafood is implied by "mariscos" in Costa Rica?

Tags: comida, costa-rica

I hope to travel to Costa Rica in the coming months. I am allergic to many types of seafood: shellfish (shrimp, clams, oysters, crabs, etc), plus octopus and squid. However, I enjoy eating fish and order it often in restaurants.  In the US I am able to tell a server at a restaurant "I am allergic to seafood" and cover all my bases, including possible cross-contamination during preparation.

At a restaurant in Costa Rica, is it sufficient to tell a server "Soy alérgico a los mariscos" in order to get this same message across? Or will I need to list out the individual food items (los camarones, el pulpo,...)?

Comment: I don't think this question is related to Spanish language. I suggest you sending an email to the [Ministerio de Relaciones Exteriores y Culto de la República de Costa Rica](https://www.rree.go.cr/?sec=ministerio&cat=acerca&cont=1315).

Comment: mariscos would not include pescado, which is fish. Just say: **Solo puedo comer pescado pero mariscos, no**. Better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Costarican here. Glad to see you're coming over and I hope you enjoy your stay.

Mariscos is fine, so saying "*Soy alérgico (masculine) alérgica (feminine) alérgicx/alérgique (non-binary) a los mariscos*" ("*I'm allergic to seafood*") should be fine. However, take into account that fish and other types of seafood may come into contact with shellfish and therefore there is always a chance that you'll get traces of them in your food, even if you didn't order shellfish

Comment: mariscos is not seafood. mariscos can be understood as: shellfish.

Comment: shellfish are a type of seafood, but I get what you mean